# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings during WSO2 IS startup

Tags: wso2-identity-server

One of my WSO2 IS (Identity Server) went poof due to physical host error, and when I want to bring back up the IS service, it just hangs and won't start up right after these warning message:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://539.fwk120694604:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.6.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api%23identity%23entitlement/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Aside of IS process hanging, there is no logs generated as well, so as per the warning messages said, there are conflicting logging classes for WSO2 IS, but I can't find this class whereabout:

> bundleresource://539.fwk120694604:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class

My current WSO2 IS version is 5.6.0 and due to some restriction I can't upgrade the version and I don't think versioning is the issue here.

I had search all over the internet but mostly involve edit pom / maven kinda stuffs but WSO2 IS is supposed to be ready product right? Well, thus until now I still can't find any solution.

Can any kind soul help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is thrown as a warn in WSO2IS

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://540.fwk1316864772:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/maneesha/WSO2/Stackoverflow/wso2is-5.6.0/wso2is-5.6.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api%23identity%23entitlement/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

This happens because there is an `SLF4J` jar file in

- `<IS-HOME>/repository/components/plugins/slf4j.log4j12_1.6.1.jar`
- `<IS-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#identity#entitlement/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar`

both contain the `StaticLoggerBinder.class` this could have been avoided using dependency management while building the `api#identity#entitlement.war` file.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/ed3e0a150adb8363f2bbd7f91a249b66c069a992/components/entitlement/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.endpoint/pom.xml#L85

As you can see there is no scope provided, can use the below dependency management to make the SLF4J lib not to bundled into  `api#identity#entitlement.war` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Meaning I need to recompile myself?

Comment: This gives only a warning, so no need to do anything WSO2IS will run smoothly